# disable dbclick event in Handson Grid

Tags: c#, jquery, handsontable

I am Using Handson table in my project. I am getting issue related to 
double-click function.

**Step 1**. I add the grey color on button click With Handson Table.

**Step 2**. After that when I double-click on cell for add/edit value, then grey color of cell automatically disabled.

How I set grey color into cell? This is example of my problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [
        ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 1],
        ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 0],
        ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 1]
    ];
    var rowcount;
    var d = $("#example1grid").handsontable({
        data: data,
        colHeaders: ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        var hot = this.instance;
        rowcount = hot.countRows() - hot.countEmptyRows();
            return cellProperties;
        },
    });

    var buttons = {
        file: document.getElementById('btnBGColor')
    };

    buttons.file.addEventListener('click', function () {
        $("td").attr('style', 'background:rgb(238,238,238) !important');
    });
});
```

Please see the error here: http://jsfiddle.net/AmanMiddha_124/q460kyba/

Comment: Please paste the error into your question, links, unlike diamonds, are not forever.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.